# How can i extract ul tag content and p tag content inside <dd> tag using regular expresstion in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want extract content from `<dd>` tag where i want to take p tag content and ul tag content i tried with preg_match_all in php to take all the contents inside the `<dd>` in that html page but get nothing this is my html code

```
<dd style="display: block;">
                                    <p>Lightweight, comfy and cool - the dressy shirt he won\'t mind wearing!</p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Made of 100% cotton</li>                        
                                        <li>Specially treated for a soft feel</li>                      
                                        <li>Classically styled with a pointed collar and button front</li>                      
                                        <li>Chest pocket; curved shirttail hem</li>                     
                                        <li>Canvas taping at inner neck</li>                        
                                        <li>Imported</li>                       
                                    </ul>


                                    <div id="BVSecondaryCustomerRatings" style="display:none;margin-left: 15px" class="BVBrowserWebkit"> <div class="BVRRRootElement">
<div class="BVRRRatingSummary BVRRSecondaryRatingSummary">
<div class="BVRRRatingSummary BVRRPrimaryRatingSummary"><div class="BVRRRatingSummaryStyle2"><div class="BVRRRatingSummaryNoReviews"> <div id="BVRRRatingSummaryNoReviewsWriteImageLinkID" class="BVRRRatingSummaryLink BVRRRatingSummaryNoReviewsWriteImageLink">
<a name="BV_TrackingTag_Rating_Summary_2_WriteReview_I2613L0022" target="BVFrame" href="http://reviews.childrensplace.com/4154/I2613L0022/writereview.htm?format=embedded&amp;campaignid=BV_RATING_SUMMARY_ZERO_REVIEWS&amp;sessionparams=__BVSESSIONPARAMS__&amp;return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.childrensplace.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2Fproduct_10001_10001_-1_1005476_827676_26601%257C72469%257C813599_boy%257Coutfits%257Cplaid%2520patrol_boy&amp;innerreturn=http%3A%2F%2Freviews.childrensplace.com%2F4154%2FI2613L0022%2Freviews.htm%3Fformat%3Dembedded&amp;user=__USERID__&amp;authsourcetype=__AUTHTYPE__&amp;submissionparams=__BVSUBMISSIONPARAMETERS__&amp;submissionurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.childrensplace.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2FTCPCheckUserAuthenticationCmd%3FlangId%3D-1%26catalogId%3D10001%26storeId%3D10001"> <img src="http://reviews.childrensplace.com/static/4154/translucent.gif" alt="Write a review">
</a> </div>
<div id="BVRRRatingSummaryLinkWriteFirstID" class="BVRRRatingSummaryLink BVRRRatingSummaryLinkWriteFirst">
<span class="BVRRRatingSummaryLinkWriteFirstPrefix">Be the first to review this item.</span>
<a name="BV_TrackingTag_Rating_Summary_2_SocialBookmarkKaboodle_I2613L0022" target="_blank" class="BVRRSocialBookmarkingSharingLink BVRRSocialBookmarkingSharingLinkKaboodle" onclick="this.href=bvReplaceTokensInSocialURL(this.href);window.open(this.href,'','left=0,top=0,width=795,height=700,toolbar=1,location=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1'); return false;" onfocus="this.href=bvReplaceTokensInSocialURL(this.href);" rel="nofollow" href="http://reviews.childrensplace.com/4154/share.htm?site=Kaboodle&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.childrensplace.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2Fproduct_10001_10001_-1_1005476&amp;title=__TITLE__&amp;robot=__ROBOT__&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.childrensplace.com%2Fwww%2Fb%2FTCP%2Fimages%2Fstyles%2F188410_m.jpg" onmouseover="this.href=bvReplaceTokensInSocialURL(this.href);"><img width="16" height="16" class="BVRRSocialBookmarkLinkImage" src="http://reviews.childrensplace.com/static/4154/link-kaboodle.gif" alt="Kaboodle" title="Add To Kaboodle"></a>
</div></div></div></div> </div>
</div>
                                    <p class="TCP-Phrase">Big Fashion, Little Prices</p>

                                    <div id="product_social_icons" style="height: 20px;">








                                            <div class="social_icon current_social">
                                                <div class="twitter"><iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1336551279.html#_=1336767195241&amp;count=horizontal&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=en&amp;original_referer=http://www.childrensplace.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10001_10001_-1_1005476&amp;size=m&amp;text=The Childrens Place - plaid shirt&amp;url=http://www.childrensplace.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10001_10001_-1_1005476" class="twitter-share-button twitter-count-horizontal" style="height: 20px; width: 90px;" title="Twitter Tweet Button"></iframe></div>
                                                <div class="pinterest" id="pin_it">
                                                    <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://pinit-cdn.pinterest.com/pinit.html?url=http://www.childrensplace.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10001_10001_-1_1005476&amp;media=//content.childrensplace.com/www/b/TCP/images/cloudzoom/p/188410_p.jpg&amp;description=plaid shirt&amp;layout=horizontal" style="border: medium none; width: 90px; height: 20px;"></iframe>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fb-like-btn" id="fb-root">
                                                    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
                                                    <fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="90" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class="fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"><span style="height: 20px; width: 76px;"><iframe id="f111d3371c" name="f5f7b234c" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 76px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D23%23cb%3Df11898a314%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.childrensplace.com%252Ff210aed7%26domain%3Dwww.childrensplace.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.childrensplace.com%2Fwebapp%2Fwcs%2Fstores%2Fservlet%2Fproduct_10001_10001_-1_1005476_827676_26601%257C72469%257C813599_boy%257Coutfits%257Cplaid%2520patrol_boy&amp;node_type=link&amp;width=90&amp;font=arial&amp;layout=button_count&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;extended_social_context=false"></iframe></span></fb:like></div>
                                            </div>



                                    </div>
                                </dd>
```

i googled alot to figure out this problem i tried with dom parsing but client need regex parsing instead of that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that doesn't tell you that your approach is ethically wrong:

```
$pattern = "/<dd.*?>.*?<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<ul>(.*?)<\/ul>/s";
if (preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches)) {
    echo "P-tag content: ".$matches[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "UL-tag content: ".$matches[2];
}
```

I tested it with the HTML you posted and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regex to parse html, IT IS WRONG.
Try to use simplexml instead, if that's too much for you, try query path: http://querypath.org/

Comment: No you are not stuck with that. Regex should never be used to parse html, never ever ever .... ever. You have alternatives, please use those, use the correct tool for the right job.